# Blocking rogue DHCP server on OSX

Tags: networking, macos, dhcp, rogue

Our LAN has two DHCP servers, one giving 10.x.x.x addresses and one giving 192.168.x.x addresses. The network guys refuse to fix the obvious misconfiguration, and in Linux I have successfully resolved the problem by adding the following line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, which ignores any DHCP offers from the rogue DHCP server:

```
reject 192.168.100.1;
```

How can I ignore the rogue DHCP server in OSX?

Comment: The real problem here seems to be your network guys.

Comment: Can't you block `192.168.100.*` in the firewall?

Comment: @MrEthernet Totally agree but need to do some work here also :)